# Bookmarks do not show up in context menu of the Nautilus launcher (Unity, X11, Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: unity, nautilus, 17.10

I recently made the jump from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10 and since I use an Nvidia graphics card and a HiDPI display, I have to use Unity (which I don't mind).

In the Unity launcher, I used to be able to right-click the Nautilus icon to bring up a list of options including my bookmarks.

Now, the menu only includes the options "New Window", "Files", and "Unlock from Launcher", no bookmarks.

The funny thing is, when I already have a Nautilus window open and then right-click the launcher icon, it shows all the bookmarks as well!

Even crazier, when I then go ahead and close all open Nautilus windows, the bookmarks continue to show up in the right-click menu for some time (a minute or two) before they disappear again.

I strongly preferred the way it worked before when I could navigate to my bookmarks directly from the right-click menu. Is there any way this behavior can be restored?

Please help!

Comment: Please help with what? If you want to have the old behavior back, your implicit question here (please try to be explicit next time), it won't happen. It depends on upstream (Gnome), nothing that Ubuntu devs can (easily) solve.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not make myself clear, but I don't know how else to describe it. I will try to take some screenshots to show what I mean

Comment: I know what you meant and I guess I understood your implicit question. If not, please correct me. However, if I'm right, again, nothing to do, live with it from now on.

Comment: I don't know what _you_ mean by implicit question. Why does it have anything to do with Gnome? I am still using the Unity desktop.
Here are links to the screenshots:
When Nautilus is not open (no boomarks): https://ibb.co/fHHcAG

When Nautilus is open (bookmarks show up): https://ibb.co/jeRFxw

Comment: I'm aware of that behavior.  And I suppose you want it to behave like before. That is exactly what WON'T happen because the changes made by Gnome to *their* software made it so and Ubuntu devs can;'t change it. BTW, pretty much everything in Unity IS Gnome already and from now on everything will be entirely Gnome in the standard Ubuntu release. So, in a nutshell, move one.

Comment: You are right, I never explicitly asked how to get the original behavior back.  I edited my question to make that clearer.

I sincerely hope that your answer is not the final one on this issue. Maybe someone knows a workaround.

Comment: There is no workaround. At best if one set nautilus to use a custom .desktop you could get them all the time But once nautilus is open you'd get double entries. (- here I've given up on nautilus & use nemo instead to be the default file manager..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this situation persists with Ubuntu 18.04, and it seems that there [won't be an official solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1720594) to it, here is a workaround:

**1.** Hit SUPER button and type in nautilus
 **2.** Drag the listed icon named "Files" to your desktop.
    Open that "org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop" file in an editor and add the 
entries you would like to be shown in the context-menu:

There are 2 relevant additions to make for each new entry:

**a)** Add your entry to the line Actions followed by a ";"

> "Actions=new-window;ADDYOURENTRYHERE;"

**b)** Copy the following 3 lines for every entry you add at the end of the file, and modify them:

> [Desktop Action ADDYOURENTRYHERE]
> Name=ADDYOURENTRYHERE
>  Exec=nautilus /home/path/to/your/desired/folder

**3.** And finally but **important**, **save the "org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop"
    launcher in a different location** then the original, for example
    /home/launchers/, because then, even if NAUTILUS is opened with this
    launcher, you won't have doubled entries in the context menu.

**4.** Now drag and drop the launcher file, out of the location where you
    saved it, to the UNITY launcher.

p.s.
obviously the downside is that this attempt is static, so you have to add and delete folders listed manually.
But it helps me, so i hope it may help someone else too (-: